# Get a reference to the calling object in a Javascript ASP.NET Ajax callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am calling an ASP.NET Ajax method (e.g. a method tagged with `[Ajax.AjaxMethod]`) on a control which is dynamically created in JavaScript when the user clicks a link (basically it is inside a table, and when the link is clicked a tr/td is built out in JS code and added to the table).  In the callback function I need to know what row is being called since I'm appending data to an input control in that row only; I have a hidden field that contains the total number of items added, but I cannot use this as it always adds to the *last* row (since it is incremented when a new row is added) not the row which is firing the function.

Something like the following:

```
// fieldName is a lookup string...
function loadOperators(fieldName) { 
    MyPage.LoadOperatorsFor(fieldName, loadOperators_Callback);
}

function loadOperators_Callback(response) { 
    var currentRow = // how to obtain this?

    // do other stuff here...
}
```

I am also using jQuery but the methods are done in ASP.NET AJAX style as that's the current style we use at work.

How am I able to determine the actual row which is firing the Ajax function, so I only populate the dropdown list contained in that row (I cannot rely on the user creating a row, and then populating that row; they might create say 5 rows and then go back to Row #2 and select something, so I would have to know they chose a value in Row #2 and not 3/4/5)?  It doesn't seem to be part of the response object, but the Callback function doesn't seem to take any additional parameters.

The only thing I can think of doing would be to add it to my AjaxMethod so it would be passed back in the response, but this seems like a hack at best since I return a DataSet and the row number has no bearing on the data.

I forgot to add, I am **not** using the ASP.NET AJAX library, only jQuery and tagging methods with `[Ajax.AjaxMethod]`

Comment: Pass the current row from the server into your ajax callback

Comment: Unless I do what I said in my edited final paragraph, the current row exists only on the client-side, not the server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I was able to solve this by simply using an inline anonymous function so I can reference the lineNumber from the calling method, instead of passing a function reference.  Simply and effective.

Answer (score 1):

You need pass a delegate as your call back parameter

```
function loadOperators(fieldName) { 
    MyPage.LoadOperatorsFor(fieldName, Function.createDelegate({"fieldName":fieldName},loadOperators_Callback));
}
```

and in your callback you can

```
function loadOperators_Callback(response) { 
    var currentRow = this.fieldName;
    // do other stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All ASP.NET AJAX web service javascript proxies allow you to pass in a context like so:

```
MyPage.LoadOperatorsFor(fieldName, loadOperators_CallBack,
                        loadOperators_Error, context);
```

The `loadOperators_Error` is your error handler, and `context` can be anything you want - in your case, pass in the currentRow.

Then on your response, you'll have:

```
function loadOperators_CallBack(response, context) {
   // context is your currentRow value
}
```

Comment: I am trying this as follows: MyPage.LoadOperatorsFor(fieldName, loadOperators_Callback, null, lineNumber) but in the Callback, lineNumber is coming back as undefined.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here's some additional information on the structure of the methods - [Service methods](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Reference.Generated-Proxy-Classes-Web-Service-Methods.ashx) and [Callbacks](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Reference.Generated-Proxy-Classes-Succeeded-Callback-Function.ashx). Double-check that you're passing in the lineNumber properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
// fieldName is a lookup string...
function loadOperators(fieldName) { 
    // assume this is a click handler on the row
    // if it isn't somehow get the row.
    var row = $(this);
    MyPage.LoadOperatorsFor(fieldName, loadOperators_Callback.bind(row));
}

function loadOperators_Callback(response) { 
    var currentRow = this;

    // do other stuff here...
}
```

Get the row in your loadOperators function then bind the `this` scope to the row in your callback. You may need to emulate `Function.prototype.bind` in IE<9. I recommend [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) for the emulation.

Actaully you can use `$.proxy(row, loadOperators_Callback)` for this.